# Can't view all attributes of an object in Schema builder

Tags: apex, schema

I'm currently trying to display all of the attributes that an object has so I can determine the appropriate field to use for what I need to do. When I click on the option "view object" on a schema in the schema builder, there is only a subset of fields displayed, but in the dev console, when you use intellisense (text completion) with the dot operator all of the attributes are displayed.

**Why is it that I can see all of the attributes of an object (including e.g. Id, created_date, last_modified_date) in the text completion but when I look at the schemas and object layouts, only a subset of the fields are displayed (including the custom and standard fields)? Also, how do I display all fields outside of intellisense?**

Comment: Because it's a UI and they need to take UX considerations into account when building it. The view would be horrible if they tried to shove 500 fields into one box.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I updated the question. I also wanted to know how to actually display all fields outside of intellisense.

Comment: If you want to view all fields, use the object view from the Setup menu, not Schema Builder. It's different for standard objects (listed individually under `Customize`) versus custom objects (listed under `Create` > `Objects`). Have you tried viewing the objects this way?